# No option to create new documents (excel, word etc) in completely new SharePoint On Premise 2019

Tags: sharepoint-server

I have installed SharePoint server 2019 on 4 servers in minrole configuration.
The installation went without issues. However, there is no option to create new documents (word excel etc.) when you hit on "New" button in the document library. (only folder and link options are visible).

Is it really necessary to install OOS or this option for creation on new documents should come out of the box?

Do you have any ideas what the issue can be?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, at present, if you want to create office files directly in SharePoint, you can only use OOS.
OOS provides the ability to create and edit Office documents directly in the browser without having to download and upload the documents. It also provides additional features such as co-authoring and real-time collaboration:

> Office Online Server delivers browser-based versions of Word,
> PowerPoint, Excel, and OneNote. A single Office Online Server farm can
> support users who access Office files through SharePoint Server,
> Exchange Server, shared folders, and web sites.

So, you can try to [Deploy Office Online Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/officeonlineserver/deploy-office-online-server).

Of course, if you don't want to install OOS, you can also choose to create office files locally and upload them to SharePoint.

Comment: Thanks a lot for provided feedback. After installation on OOS server the options for creation on office documents become visible. However I am experiencing issues when opening documents:
Excel:
We couldn't find the file you wanted. It's possible the file was renamed, moved or deleted.
Word: Sorry there was a problem and we can`t open this document
PowerPoint: Sorry we can`t open this presentation because we ran into a problem.
For OneNote it is only loading but did not display any error message.
The following URL:
https://servername/hosting/discovery is returning XML file as expected.